# merge two JavaScript objects with priority

Tags: javascript, merge

I have two JavaScript objects like

```
let master = {A:0, B:2};
let slave = {B:1, C:1};
```

I need:

```
result == {A:0, B:2, C:1};
```

Does JS have a simple command to merge in that way?

Comment: These are not "JSON".

Comment: Try googling "merge objects javascript".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

> The **`Object.assign()`** method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

```js
let master = {A:0, B:2};
let slave = {B:1, C:1};

console.log(Object.assign(slave, master));
```

Comment: nice. (offtopic: code snippet don't work in firefox for me, but nice in chrome)